# How do I carry out a calculation on a frame of a video using open cv?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm trying to carry out a blob detection on every 10th frame of a video file, how do I find the x,y coordinates for each frame?

I'm new to both python and opencv and I'm trying to use an if statement that will find the x,y coordinates of a blob on a video every 10 frames, I've got the if statement to return every 10th frame but now I cant work out how I would find the x,y coordinates for each. Would I have to save each image and then carry out the calculation or is there a simpler way?

```
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('testing.mov')
count = 0
fps = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
length = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

while count < length:
    count += 1
    if count % 10 == 0:
```

I would like the if statement to return the x,y coordinates for every 10th frame so that I can carry out further calculations on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grab every frame using `VideoCapture.read()` and process as needed.

```
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('testing.mov')
count = 0
fps = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
length = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

while count < length:
    count += 1

    # read the next frame
    ret, frame = vidcap.read()

    # if read fail, then break
    if not ret: break

    if count % 10 == 0:
       # frame contains the detail you need, do your calculation here
```